# Orchard CMS Warmup Status Zero

Tags: orchardcms

I have setup a brand new Orchard CMS 1.5.1 site using Web Platform Installer on Windows 2008 Server.  I wanted to test out the Performance settings so I configured the following Warmup entries one per line:

/

/blog

...and checked the following options:

x Generate warmup pages periodically 90 Every minutes

x Generate warmup pages any time some content is published

When I visit the site the performance was still a bit slow.  The Performance Warmup settings show each page has a status of zero and a red "down arrow" icon next to it.

Is there anything else I need to enable?  Is there anything I am missing in the configuration like permissions, etc.

**UPDATE:**

I have noticed that my site does not have a folder to store the warm up pages.  I added that folder manually but it still didn't fix my problems.  Are there permissions I would need to set on that folder?

**UPDATE 2:**

After talking with Sebastien Ros, I think I understand what is wrong but still don't know how to fix it.  The base URL setting in Orchard is set to "www.mydomain.com" as it should be but networking-wise my server does not allow my site to go out to the internet and query itself by that address in order to generate the warm-up page. To make matters worse, I have several sites that are hosted on the same IP address and using host headers to distinguish between sites.  This prevents me from even being able to configure the base URL as a local IP address (which cause issues with other modules anyway).

Not sure what alternatives I have now.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed with a Network Engineer at my server host that there was a networking restriction on outgoing requests coming back in for the web site.  So, the performance module could not query www.mydomain.com and get an answer.  Once the network restriction was removed, I was able see Warm-ups create the cache pages with a Status 200.

Alternatively, it was suggested that I create entries in my host file for each of my Orchard sites.  I did not try this but I see no reason why it would not work even with the host-headered scenario that I have.

Brian

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the general settings page is pointing to your base URL, i.e. http://mywebsite.com.
It may be pointing to the local host by default.

Comment: My base URL is set to the URL of the site and not local host so it must be something else. Thanks.